# $sum with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to convert a current $group with $sum to add another condition:

> Actually sum a field if a $eq return true.

Now I want to do sum a field if $eq return true and $exists return true.

My current group its this:

```js
"techsWorkQty": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [
                            "$works.TechnicianId", id
                        ]},
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Where can I add the following subquery?

```js
{
 $works.percent:{$exists:true}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator is a "query" operator only and can only be used in a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline for aggregation. In order to test for a field presence as a "logical" operator you want to use [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/). The [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) operator is used to combine logical conditions and is also a logical operator as opposed to the query form of the same name. Logical operators can be used in `$project` and `$group` stages:

```js
"techsWorkQty": {
    "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$and": [
                { "$ifNull": [ "$works.percent", false ] },
                { "$eq": [ "$works.TechnicianId", id ] }
            ]},
            1,
            0
        ]
    }
}
```

`$ifNull` returns either the field value where it is present or the alternate value specified where the field does not exist. In this case a "value" for a present field would evaluate to `true` in boolean context. Where there is not a field then the `false` argument is returned. The `$and` in boolean form requires both logical expressions to evaluate to true, otherwise in itself it returns `false` which is handled by the wrapping `$cond` to return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 4):

```
Project.aggregate([
{
            "$unwind": "$works"
        },
$group: {
_id:null,
techsWorkQty: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ['$works.percent', id]
                        },
                        then: 1,
                        else: 0
                    }
                }
            }
      }
])
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator to include multiple conditions that must be satisfied.  You can try something like this:

```js
"techsWorkQty": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$and" : [
                               {"$works.percent":{$exists:true}}, 
                               {"$eq": ["$works.TechnicianId", id]}
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
```